# execute command to select a value from table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

working with a db access and Vb net, i should want to extract a value from my table using a fast query. Actually i use this code

```
Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = DBConnect.getDbConnection()

        Try

            Dim selectSql = "select payed as P from mytable where Val(ID) = '4' "
                             
            Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(selectSql, conn)
            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "mytable")
            Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("mytable")
            Dim row As DataRow
               .....etc
```

However i remember that with ado in vb6, I could have done it in another way, something like this
`(CnMain.Execute("SELECT Payed as P From mytable Where Val(id) = '4'")("P"))`

is there a way in vbnet by some oledb command to obtain the same result?
Thanks

Comment: Sure is.  Have a look at OleDBCommands https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Are you sure that _Val(ID)_ is a correct syntax? What is the datatype of the column id? Why do you try to transform it in a number and then compare it against a string? This doesn't make much sense for me.

Comment: Ho Steve, i have used casual value and syntax. I only wanted to explain two different query setup methods. Really my problem isn't the query above, it does function correctly, rather than  writing as I described below

Comment: @Hursey reading the page of your link, i think i could use executescalar. Maybe it obtains the same result. (Maybe :-) )

Comment: Yup Execute reader, give you a heap of flexibility,  but honestly, what you're currently doing filling DataSets is effectively the same thing under the hood.  It really just saves you from doing all the legwork.  What is best really comes down to your exact requirements and personal preferences

Comment: @Hursey The fact is that when you need a lot of data from a row of the dataset or from all rows, writing a procedure like this is even more effective, but in the case of a single data that can be obtained with an execute query, it becomes easier. I think so

Comment: It would also be worth looking at ExecuteScaler which returns the value in the first row/column in your query which save you the overheads of readers, you just have to type cast the result as appropriate

Comment: Ho Jayelet. One of the requirements of a question is that the problem be reproducable. Your "casual" read lazy code does not meet the criteria. You don't convert the field to match the parameter, you convert the parameter to match the datatype of the field. You are forcing Access to convert every value in the field to a number while it searches. Much faster for you to convert a single value to the proper type.

Comment: Connections need to be declared in a `Using` block locally in the method where they are used. This way they can be disposed even if there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved writing something like this

```
Try
            Dim sql As String = "Select amount from Moneydifference where val(rfticket) = '" & tTicket & "'"
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, conn)
            Dim conto As Double = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            cmd.Dispose()

            
        Catch ex As Exception
         ....
        End Try
```

Comment: You will also want to read up on parametrizing your queries rather than using string concatenations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0.  String concatenations is the #1 reason why SQL commands don't work as expected and can be incredibly hard to debug

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a Double for money. Use Decimal.

Comment: @Mary i have just tryed using var Decimal, but it generate a problem storing number. Unsing Decimal, the number stored has format 1.16 (with dot) rather 1,16 so that Access mdb store it as 116,00 It doesn,t happen if i use a Double